# How to create a antlr4 grammar which will parse time

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

how can I parse time format using ANTLR4 grammar.
Following are the java time format with examples.

```
HH:mm:ss.SSSX"    ->  "13:16:54.123+05"
HH:mm:ss.SSS z"   ->  "13:16:54.123 PDT"
HH:mm:ss.SSS"     ->  "13:16:54.123"
HH:mm:ssX"        ->  "13:16:54+05"
HH:mm:ss z"       ->  "13:16:54+05"
HH:mm:ssz"        ->  "10:12:30 GMT-08:00"
HH:mm:ssZ"        ->  "10:12:30 -0500"
HH:mm:ssS"        ->  "10:12:30 -5:00"
HH:mm:ss"         ->  "10:12:30"
```

Comment: Actually I am converting the ALTER command SQL queries from one DB to another DB so that it may compatible.

Comment: E.g: from Postgres to SQL Server etc the Alter command varies . 
'ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN? columnName SET DEFAULT date  SCOLON'

Comment: For your reference, click on 
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Comment: First I need to verify using Antlr weather the user enter the correct query to parse. then After I will use 'SimpleDateFormat' if required.